# Is this Dua, about meeting people, authentic?

Tags: dua

Oh Allah, bring me close to those whom You have brought close to Yourself, and connect me to those whom You have connected to Yourself.

Comment: It sounds like a good dua, alhamdulilah. Why does it matter whether it is authentic?

Comment: So I could find the correct Arabic for it and say it in salah. For example, if it wasn't authentic, I would have to go through the hassle of translating it into Arabic with an expert. Kind of weird, I know, but this is why I only make duas that the prophet was known to make in my salah. Keep things simple for myself.

Comment: َاللَّهُمَّ قَرِبْنِيْ مِمَّنْ اِقْتَرَبْتَ بِنَفْسِكَ وَ رَبَطْنِيْ مِمَّنْ رَبَطْتَنِيْ بِنَفْسِك

Comment: Jazakallah////////